# Azure Service Bus Queue OnMessageOptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I am using service bus queue and came across OneMessage mechanism which processes messages as and when they arrive. There is a parameter associated which I read about "MaxConcurrentCalls". I know what this parameter is and how it works. But what is the default value of this parameter, If I dont mention anything.
Is it 1? it can't be zero i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `1`. Decompiled `Microsoft.ServiceBus` and see the following in `OnMessage` constructor :)

[image]